# I am having dependency issues installing Redujx-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, package.json, redux-toolkit

When I'm using useSelector Hook from react-redux, sometimes I got a error says: "useSyncExternalStore is not a function". I tried to search google to fix the problems, but i didn't find anything.

Here's my full code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-k7tfxu?file=components%2FTodoList.tsx

TodoList.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { useAppSelector } from '../app/hooks';

const TodoList = () => {
  //if I remove this line, it's work fine!
  const list = useAppSelector((state) => state.todos.list);

  return (
    <ul>
      <TodoItem {...list} />
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

store.tsx

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import todosReducer from './features/todos-slice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todos: todosReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

my custom Hooks

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

createSlice file

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TodoState } from '../../interface';

interface Todos {
  list: TodoState[];
}

const initialState: Todos = {
  list: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Learn Javascript',
      done: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Learn React',
      done: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Build a React App',
      done: false,
    },
  ],
};

export const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
});

export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure all your versions are in sync. When upgrading your version of react in an on going project you will need to pay close attention to all the dependencies it has. there are some npm commands you can try.

npm install --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

this will help with older conflicting versions

Comment: This did the trick!! Thanks Justin

Answer (score 1):

I found a problems! It's new Hook from React v.18, and it's still in beta :). Sometimes, stackblitz recommended me to add newest version of react and got error. I'm use the older version and it worked beautifully

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like you installed React-Redux v8 beta, which _requires_ React 18.  That's why it's not fully released yet.